# Logical and Screen Co-ordinates

Tags: language-agnostic, layout, user-interface, geometry, coordinates

A logical coordinate to screen coordinate mapping is set up so that a diagram which has 
an extent of (-5, -4) to (+5, +6) in logical coordinates is mapped onto a screen with pixel 
co-ordinates from 0,0 to 300, 400. The user clicks on pixel 200,300. What does this 
correspond to in the logical co-ordinates of the diagram?

Do we create the matrix (30x 40y 1)? and then 200=30x => x=6.67 300=40y => y=7.5 ???

Comment: SO is not for doing your homework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For X you need a mapping from (0, 300) to (-5, +5).  Therefore you need a linear function f(x) such that f(0)=-5 and f(300)=+5.  You can write that down by inspection as:

```
f(x) = -5 + [(+5 - -5)/(300 - 0)]x
     = -5 + (10/300)x
```

You can apply the same logical trivially to the other axis.

This problem is simplified by the fact that the top left of your screen rectangle is at (0,0) but even if this was not the case, the same principle can be followed.

Comment: Thanks a lot. That was really helpful. The result is the same using the matrix as i shown above but subtracting the translation X and Y in each case. i.e x=6.67-5=1.67 and y=7.5-4=3.5

Comment: Clearly you can do the same linear transformation with a matrix, but I don't think you gain anything doing so. If this answers your question then please remember to mark it as the accepted answer.